# What difference does curly brace make in accessing an object

Tags: perl

Not even sure if I used the right terminology..
This was the passed data.

```perl
$bug = bless({
'bug_id' => '25252',

'flag_types' => [
    bless({
      'name' => 'name1',
      'flags' => [bless({
        'id' => 488052,
      }, 'Bugzilla::Flag')],
    }, 'Bugzilla::FlagType'), 
    bless({
      'name' => 'name2',
      'flags' => [bless({
        'id' => 488053,
      }, 'Bugzilla::Flag')],
    }, 'Bugzilla::FlagType'), 
  ],

}, 'Bugzilla::Bug');
```

Why can I reference `name` with or without curly braces, but not the `flags`?
`$_->flags` gives error

```
Can't locate object method "flags"
```

```perl
                my @isCrash = map { 
                    print Dumper($_->name);
                    print Dumper($_->{name});
                    print Dumper($_->flags); # errors
                    print Dumper($_->{flags};                    
                } @{ $bug->{flag_types} };
```

I get that `flags` is not a method, but why is it that I don't get such an error for `name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array contains objects of type [Bugzilla::FlagType](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/FlagType.html), they have a method `name` that "Returns the name of the flagtype".

Comment: so when I do `$_->name`, it executed the method without having `()` at the end? Interesting..!

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers Perl does not require the parenthesis `()` in most cases for function or method calls. If you pass arguments into a method call, you have to use them, but not for empty argument lists.